# How do I structure adding methods to a class in Python to import them

Tags: python

New to Python here - coming from Perl, so have mercy If I'm asking perl-ish things.

I am trying to extend the functionality of an existing Python class ([svgpathtools](https://pypi.org/project/svgpathtools/)) via an additional module.

In other words, I would like to have in one file somewhere (AKA the module providing the extension):

```
def foo(path_a, path_b):
    d=0
    for t in range(0, 101, 1):
        d = d + complex_distance(path_a.point(t / 100), path_b.point(t / 100))
    return d / 100

setattr(svgpathtools.Path, 'foo', foo)
```

and then in the file using the extension

be able to do something like this:

```
import svgpathtools.foo

some_path.foo(some_other_path)
```

I'd like to know:

- how to name/where to save the file extending the svpathtools module (i.e.: what's the mapping between module name and file name)
- what should it look like in order to monkey-patch the svgtools methods

My biggest problem is finding out what this kind of stuff is called - so I can do my own googling. Full explanations are appreciated, but pointers for further research are enough for me to get going.

Comment: Why not use conventional inheritance?

Comment: Don't worry, it takes time to detox from Perl. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if patching stuff outside tests is appropriate. IMHO It's better to inherit from base class, or simply declare this function as standalone and call it directly, w/o referring to svgpathtools. setattr on import is not... explicit to the end user, if you still need to patch, please, wrap it in some sort of `install` function

Comment: More seriously, Perl and Python have *very* different ideas about how classes are implemented. In Perl, a class is just a package. In Python, a class is quite distinct from a module (and a package is just a module that contains other modules). `svgpathtools` itself is not a class at all; it's a module. `svgtools.Path` is an attribute of  that module whose value is a class. While you *can* add a new method to an existing class, it's more likely you want to use inheritance or composition to define a *new* class to use instead.

Comment: As far as I can recall, Perl doesn't even support inheritance in the language; there's a separate library for defining an inheritance relationship between two packages. Perl 6 / Raku might have changed that, but I never had any need (or much desire) to learn that language.

Comment: @chepner - I'm actually enjoying switching back and forth, like being able to appreciate English and Italian - different, both good. No detox planned, or needed. I do miss things such as roles (https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny) and method modifiers (https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Method::Modifiers) which make extending classes much less complex

Comment: @chepner - inheritance is handled via ```base``` https://perldoc.perl.org/base

Comment: @simone Thanks; somehow, I overlooked the existence of that even when I *was* trying to write OO Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a method is merely an attribute of a class that happens to be a function having the object (by convention called `self`) as its first argument. And a class is just an object. So patching a class to add new methods or replace existing (it is called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)) is trivial. But inheritance is a much cleaner way to obtain the same result: the new behaviour is encapsulated in a distinct class having a distinct name, which can save later maintenance headaches...

Here is a trivial example with a base class that can compute the double of its original value, and an extension that can compute the quad (* 4):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._val = a
    def double(self):
        return 2 * self._val
```

Example usage:

```
>>> a = A(2)
>>> a.double()
4
```

Let us derive it:

```
class B(A):
    def quad(self):
        return 4 * self._val
```

which can be used that way:

```
>>> b = B(2)
>>> b.double()
4
>>> b.quad()
8
```

Here is a monkey patched version:

```
>>> A.quad = lambda self: 4 * self._val
```

which also gives

```
>>> a = A(2)
>>> a.quad()
8
```

But that way has *globally* modified the `A` class which no longer respects its initial (and hopefully documented API). Unless it is commented in red flashing font a future maintener will certainly blame you for that...

That being said, monkey patching can make sense to fix a bug in a module that you cannot (or do not want to) patch at source level...

Comment: Thanks - I'm missing a detail though: where (i.e.: in what file) should the mokey patching happen, for it to be re-usable (via ```import```)

Comment: If you want it to be importable in a standard way, you **really** should considere inheritance. You can only monkey patch a class after the module in which it is declared has been loaded. And as the patch is global, you must be cautious for side effect in other modules using the same class...